# Why is validate.errors empty after this custom keyword validation?

Tags: javascript, ajv

I am using a pair of custom keywords to ease our validation needs. So far it has worked well everywhere... but now I'm not getting the errors to persist and be detected after validation.

```
ajv.addKeyword('batch', {
    compile: function validator(batch) {
        const { limit, items } = batch;

        const arraySchema = {
            type: 'array',
            items,
            minItems: 1,
            maxItems: limit,
        };

        return ajv.compile({
            oneOf: [
                arraySchema,
                items,
            ],
        });
    },
    errors: false,
});

ajv.addKeyword('customValidator', {
    type: 'string',
    validate: function validate(schema, data) {
        try {
            if (data.length > 500) {
                throw new Error('should be <= 500 characters');
            }
            const { type } = myCustomValidator.parse(data);

            if (schema === true || schema.includes(type)) {
                return true;
            }
            throw new TypeError(`${data} must be one of the following: ${schema}`);
        } catch (error) {

            if (!validate.errors) {
                validate.errors = [];
            }
            validate.errors.push(error);
            return false;
        }
    },
    errors: true,
});
```

With then a schema like this:

```
{
    type: 'object',
    required: [
        'requiredFieldName',
    ],
    properties: {
        requiredFieldName: {
            batch: {
                items: { customValidator: ['allowedType'] },
                limit: 100,
            },
        },
        optionalFields: { customValidator: ['allowedType1', 'allowedType2'] },
    },
}
```

I then created a test that would fail causing `myCustomValidator.parse` to throw.

```
{
  requiredFieldName: ['blah', 'blah'],
}
```

Using `console.log` I can see that it throwing and is being caught and being added to the `validator.errors`. I expect the validation to fail, however at the end of the day it says it passes. Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Note: If I change the definition of the `items` in `batch` of the schema to `type: 'integer'` it fails as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it works if you specify `type: 'string'` in addition to the `customValidator` in the schema:

```
{
    type: 'object',
    required: [
        'requiredFieldName',
    ],
    properties: {
        requiredFieldName: {
            batch: {
                items: { type: 'string', customValidator: ['allowedType'] },
                limit: 100,
            },
        },
        optionalFields: { customValidator: ['allowedType1', 'allowedType2'] },
    },
}
```

Don't know why, but this is now working.